# Project not able to build in indigo

Tags: eclipse

I recently installed eclipse indigo and moved my project to it from eclipse ganymede. When I 'build' the project I got the following error.

```
 'Building Workspace' has encounted a problem
   An internal error occurred during: "Building Workspace".
```

The details of the error is as follows:

```
An internal error occurred during: "Building Workspace".
    Java heap space
```

I increased the memory to 1024m, by editing the 'eclipse.ini' as follows:

```
  -startup
 plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
  --launcher.library
  plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.100.v20110502
  -product
  org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
  --launcher.defaultAction
  openFile
  --launcher.XXMaxPermSize
  1024M
  -showsplash
  org.eclipse.platform
  --launcher.XXMaxPermSize
  1024m
  --launcher.defaultAction
  openFile
  -vmargs
  -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
  -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
```

If I make a small project (like 'Hello World'), then everything is running fine. I was not getting this problem for the older version of eclipse.

Is this a memory problem?

Comment: The heap size is set with `-Xmx1024m` (somewhere after the `vmargs` line).

Comment: I added this variable. And now the eclipse won't start. I am getting "Failed to create the JAVA Virtual Machine" error. I found that this variable is also used in ganymede. The eclipse runs if I remove this variable.

Comment: Try to set a smaller heap size - in my experience, the practical limit of the heap size is around 700-750MB on 32 bit systems. Otherwise @his solution is correct.

Comment: I just took the value from the MaxPermSize. For that it is too high, should be ~128m. I have mx 1024m on a 32 bit system.

Comment: In Indigo, is -Xmx valid? As soon as I use this variable, the eclipse won't start.

Comment: Did you import the project into a new workspace, reuse the Ganymede workspace or did you something else?

Comment: I did not import the project. I created a new project and copied the source code. Both JAVA and JSP.

Comment: Please don't edit a solution into your Question. If you want to post a solution, post it in an Answer, please. Also, please note that you shouldn't expand on your Question once there's an Answer on it.

Answer (score 1):

Your initial problem of

```
An internal error occurred during: "Building Workspace".
    Java heap space
```

is simply that: you ran out of heap space.  Your initial fix was incorrect though: instead of increasing the maximum heap size to 1024m, you increased the [permanent generation](https://blogs.oracle.com/jonthecollector/entry/presenting_the_permanent_generation) size to 1024m, which wouldn't (and didn't...) resolve your problem.

You then tried having both perm gen and maximum heap sizes set to 1024m which would also not work, as you don't have enough memory to allocate 2 gigabytes: thus, eclipse could not boot up at all.

You left it at having MaxPermSize left as default, Xms40m, and Xmx1024m.  Eclipse can be slow with those settings for at least two reasons:

**One**, you've told the JVM to start off with 40m and grow up to 1024m.  That growth in itself can be slow, so you may want to remove that as a potential problem by simply setting them both to the same value: Xms1024m and Xmx1024m.

**Two**, 1024m may simply not be enough for the size of your project(s).  You can try increasing it further, but with a 32-bit Windows machine you just can't get that much bigger.  In that case, you'll have to upgrade to a 64-bit OS and Eclipse version.

There are other potential issues.  You might have to, for example, increase the permanent generation size somewhat from the default.  In the end this is a GC tuning question, and it's a big topic.  Do some research if those above two options are not possible.

---

Note that these settings (`-XX:MaxPermSize`, `Xmx`, `Xms`) are not Indigo settings.  They are JVM settings (with documentation depending on whether it's a [standard option](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html) or a [non-standard one](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html)) which are used to configure the JVM that Indigo (as a Java application) is running in.

Finally, to answer a side question of yours: Indigo is not "optimized for 64-bit".  There is a 32-bit version and a 64-bit version, and you should use the correct one for your OS and JVM bit-ness.

Answer (score 0):

his is right.  You can get a good explanation of eclipse.ini [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini).

(edit: including my own eclipse.ini)

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.100.v20110505
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vm
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/bin
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
-Xms40m
-Xmx1536m
```

Comment: his solution does not work. Now the eclipse won't even start.

Comment: Hmm... well I have the same issue with my project at work and the same solution worked for me.  Answer edited to include my own eclipse.ini

Comment: I edited my eclipse.ini, with your values. Still eclipse won't start. Got the same error. If I remove the -Xms and -Xmx then the eclipse starts but won't build. Also, r u using Indigo? It seems these variables and not valid for it.

Comment: I am using Indigo, but I'm on a 64-bit Linux box so that lets me use a bit more memory than you.

Comment: I am using Indigo, but I'm on a 64-bit Linux box with lots of RAM so that lets me use a bit more memory than you.
Unfortunately I'm almost out of ideas; you could iteratively try increasing your max heap size a little at a time (-Xmx256m, -Xmx288m, then -Xmx320m, etc) until your project builds, and if you want to keep an eye on what the VM is doing under the hood, check out VisualVM (http://visualvm.java.net/). Good luck.

(oops, was too fast posting the previous comment)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I seem to be getting more problems with each new version of eclipse.. :`( ...